# Foreach IPv4 address where name is like 10.53.* get user logged on

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find out who is in the office and who's not by checking the IPv4 Address range.
Anyone with an IP address starting with 10.57.xx.xx Is in the office and anyone with IP 10.53.xx.xx is working on a VPN.
I would like to export their domain usernames from the list of people in the office.

How can I do this using PowerShell?

This is what I have (unfinished)

```
$Machines = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Laptops,OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com').Name
$result = foreach ($Machine in $Machines) 
{ 
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Machine -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        if($machine.ipaddress -like "10.57*")
        {
            Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $Machine –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Username
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a record of which employees have what devices? If not then the only way to find out who is logged into which machine is to query the Domain Controller security logs (all of them) or to query the machines directly for who is currently logged in.

Comment: @scepticalist - I'm sure there is a way to Use the list of computer names in AD, querying the IPAddress, then using the first two octets to determine the user's location, then with that, using GetWMI to query the last user logged in? I just cant compile all this into a script :(

Comment: Yes, you can, just take it one step at a time. I'd advise compiling the user/IP list first because querying workstations is going to take some time. Give it a try, post the code here and people can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

````
#Query machines, better use dnsHostName instead of name. The ldapfilter does only return enabled accounts
$Machines = (Get-ADComputer -ldapfilter "(&(samaccountname=*)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))" -SearchBase 'OU=Laptops,OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com').dnsHostName
$result = @(
    foreach ($Machine in $Machines){
        try {
            #Test connection, remove -quiet otherwise you wont get infos like IP
            $contest = Test-Connection -ComputerName $Machine -Count 1 -ErrorAction:Stop
        }
        Catch {
            write-warning "Machine: $machine is not pingable - process next item"
            continue
        }
        if($contest.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString -match "^(10\.57)"){
            #WMI is a bit outdated you should use CIM instead
            #Get-WmiObject –ComputerName $Machine –Class Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object Username
            #Switched to EventLog as Win32_ComputerSystem does not give you the necessary information, will only detect the newest logon event of logon type 2 (logon locally)
            try {
                [xml[]]$xml = Get-WinEvent -ErrorAction:stop -ComputerName $machine -ProviderName "Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4624] and EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType'] and (Data='2')]]" -MaxEvents 1 | %{$_.ToXml()}
            }
            Catch {
                write-error "Failed to query EventLog - Exception: $_"
                continue
            }
            $userName = ($xml.event.EventData.data | ?{$_.name -eq 'targetusername'}).'#text'
            $inOffice = $true
        }
        Else {
            $username = $null
            $inOffice = $false
        }
        #Build object 
        $attrsht = [ordered]@{
            user=$userName
            machine=$Machine
            isInOffice=$inOffice
            ipAddress=$contest.IPV4Address.IPAddressToString
        }
        new-object -TypeName psobject -Property $attrsht
    }
)
$result | export-csv C:\inOfficeReport.csv -delimiter ";" -notypeinformation```
````

Comment: Thats Magic thank you. It doesn't seem to give me all the info I need in the results

user machine                
    isInOffice ipAddress

---- -------                    ---------- ---------

     LN-T4       True
   
  LN-T1       True

Comment: sorry can't follow you - what is missing? you want more info in the returned object or are some attributes empty?

Comment: true @theo.... I'll update the code

Comment: I get a list of machines that are not pingable, then a list which are but the columns aren't all populating. The User and IP address columns are empty

Comment: in case of a machine is not pingable you only should get the warning message displayed, but those machines should not be part of the array $result - right? that the username is missing was related to to a mistake I did, also I switched the approach to the eventLog. but that the IP information is missing... hmm strange, need to check later

Comment: I've resolved the IP and username issue. I'll edit the script above with my changes, I appreciate your help!

Comment: ok even better :-)

Comment: Can anyone help me remove the blank fields from the results?

Comment: which code you are curently using? my latest version or a updated version of your own code? still an issue with username/ip?

Comment: No issue with Username or IP. My csv just returns some blank fields and I want to filter them out. is this possible?